# How to resize Window to loaded Image?

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

Is there a way that to resize the window in SDL to fit the loaded image size? currently when you resize it copies what was behind the window.
This is my Load Image Function:

```
void userImage(SDL_Surface *surface, SDL_Window *window)
{
    SDL_Surface *userLoadImage;
    char FileLocation[200];

    printf( "Please Enter the file location:\n" );
    fgets(FileLocation, 200, stdin );
    fflush(stdin);
    FileLocation[strcspn(FileLocation,"\n")]=0;
    char *const picturePath = FileLocation;

    userLoadImage = IMG_Load( picturePath );
    int width = userLoadImage->w; //Get the width
    int height = userLoadImage ->h;  //Get the height

    printf("image width = %d\n", width);
    printf("image width = %d\n", height);
    SDL_BlitSurface(userLoadImage, NULL, surface, NULL);
    SDL_SetWindowSize( window, width, height);
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could point them out, I'm still learning ( most of my code is C, but I needed some C++ functionality that made things easier ). Thanks

Comment: Changing your `printf` to `cout` statements would add some simple C++ functionality, for example.  (printf is legal in both C++ and C though)

Comment: I changed my answer to one that is more SDL centric.  Sorry for the mis-understanding.

Comment: No Worries, but thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I fixed it: All i changed was to reassign the window to the surface 'surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);'

```
void userImage(SDL_Surface *surface, SDL_Window *window)
{
    SDL_Surface *userLoadImage;
    char FileLocation[200];

    printf( "Please Enter the file location:\n" );
    fgets(FileLocation, 200, stdin );
    fflush(stdin);
    FileLocation[strcspn(FileLocation,"\n")]=0;
    char *const picturePath = FileLocation;

    userLoadImage = IMG_Load( picturePath );
    int width = userLoadImage->w; //Get the width
    int height = userLoadImage ->h;  //Get the height
    SDL_SetWindowSize( window, width, height);

    surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    SDL_BlitSurface(userLoadImage, NULL, surface, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an SDL method for *scaling a surface* that may do what you are looking for:

```
SDL_Surface* SDL_ScaleSurface(SDL_Surface *Surface, Uint16 Width, Uint16 Height)
{
    for(Sint32 y = 0; y < Surface->h; y++) //Run across all Y pixels.
        for(Sint32 x = 0; x < Surface->w; x++) //Run across all X pixels.
            for(Sint32 o_y = 0; o_y < _stretch_factor_y; ++o_y) //Draw _stretch_factor_y pixels for each Y pixel.
                for(Sint32 o_x = 0; o_x < _stretch_factor_x; ++o_x) //Draw _stretch_factor_x pixels for each X pixel.
                    DrawPixel(_ret, static_cast<Sint32>(_stretch_factor_x * x) + o_x, 
                        static_cast<Sint32>(_stretch_factor_y * y) + o_y, ReadPixel(Surface, x, y));
}
```

The example, and much more is on *[this page](http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-scale-surface)*.